# Box Probability

Tags: probability

Two boxes are given, one containing three white and two black balls and the other containing two white and one black balls. One ball is randomly removed from each box. If $ P_1 $ is the probability that at least one ball is black and $ P_2 $ is the probability that the two balls will be the same, then $ P_1 + P_2 $

The answer is $\frac {17} {15}$, but I thought $\frac {8} {15}$, why in this case I also don't take into account the probability of choosing one of the boxes? I made:

$P_1=  \frac12\cdot \frac25 + \frac12 \cdot\frac13 + \frac12\cdot\frac25 \cdot\frac12\cdot\frac13$

$P_2 = \frac12 \cdot \frac35 \cdot \frac12\cdot\frac23 + \frac12 \cdot \frac25 \cdot \frac12 \cdot \frac13$

Comment: What does the "then $P_1 + P_2$" mean? It looks like you didn't finish the sentence.

Comment: When you go to calculate $P_1$, you are multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ seemingly at random and adding things in strange ways.  I would instead have suggested looking at this with inclusion-exclusion.  The probability of at least one black ball would be the probability that from the first box you drew black, plus the probability that from the second box we drew black, minus the probability that we drew black from both, $\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{5}\times\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Please stack your fractions.  You can write $\frac 23$ with \frac 23  For multiple characters you put them in braces, so to get $\frac {17}{15}$ you type \frac {17}{15}  They are much easier to read.  Also you should evaluate your expressions for $P_1$ and $P_2$

Comment: It seems you are multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ thinking that it has to do with us having picked that particular box at the time...  but the problem states that we *always* picked once from each box.  Multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$ might have made sense if we were choosing a box at random and then picking from it, but here no randomness is occurring in relation to the boxes themselves, the only randomness is in relation to which *ball* it was that was selected in each step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P_1 = \mathbb{P}(\textrm{at least 1 black})=1 - \mathbb{P}(\textrm{both white})$$
$$P_2 = \mathbb{P}(\textrm{both same})=\mathbb{P}(\textrm{both white})+ \mathbb{P}(\textrm{both black})$$
So $$P_1+P_2 = 1 + \mathbb{P}(\textrm{both black}) = 1 + \frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{17}{15}$$

Answer (score 0):

$P_1$ is the chance you do not get two white balls.  The chance of two white balls is $\frac 35 \cdot \frac 23=\frac 25$, so $P_1=\frac 35$.

The chance of two black balls is $\frac 25 \cdot \frac 13=\frac 2{15},$ so $P_2=\frac 25+\frac 2{15}=\frac 8{15}.$

$P_1+P_2=\frac 35+\frac 8{15}=\frac {17}{15}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P[B,W] $ be the probability that the ball form the first box is Black and the ball from the second box is White

Show that $P_1 = P[B,B]+P[B,W]+P[W,B]$ and $P_2=P[B,B]+P[B,W]$.

So $P_1 + P_2 = 1 + P[B,B] = ?$